How to import Microsoft Word files into a Next.js website and extract content?
I'm developing a website using Next.js called "Question Bank". On the admin page, there's an option to import questions via a Word file. When the user clicks the import button, a modal should display a Word program with a complete toolbar, similar to the image below, so I can paste copied data from another Word file into this modal or use an import Word button to upload my Word file's content into the modal. Then, when I press the save button, I want to log the base64 of the Word file's content from the modal to the console. How can I achieve this? Are there any tools or libraries available? I've tried some like Syncfusion, but it couldn't import complex mathematical symbols, so I think integrating Microsoft Word might be the most suitable solution.

I attempted to integrate Microsoft Word functionality into my Next.js website's admin page for importing questions. I expected to see a modal with a Word program interface where I could either paste copied content or upload a Word file. Upon clicking the save button, I anticipated logging the base64 representation of the Word file's content to the console. However, despite trying various libraries like Syncfusion, I encountered difficulties, particularly with importing complex mathematical symbols. As a result, I'm seeking advice on alternative methods or libraries to achieve this functionality seamlessly.
